# NSTextField - Input validation with KVO?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a `NSTextField` in my app, and I want to update the input when user gives me some bad input.

Also, I've bound the value of this text field control to a member variable. I've extracted a minimal project:

[image]

Here's the binding:

[image]

Eveything is simple, and finally in code I've set the initial value to `Hello, World`, and I've also implemented `controlTextDidChange:` method from `NSControlTextEditingDelegate`.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    self.text = @"Hello, World";
}

- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj
{
    NSLog(@"Changed Value: %@", [[obj object] stringValue]);
    self.text = @"What??";
}
```

When I start typing in the text field, I did get change notification, except the value in the text field is not updated. I'm wondering why and how can I update text value in the text field with change of `self.text`.

PS: I know I can do this by adding an `outlet` of that text field, and manually set `stringValue`, but I don't want to do that. Because it breaks the `low coupling` rule, right?

Comment: I did it for iOS, but it should work the same way:
(viewDidLoad): `self.textfield.delegate = self;` and the method: 
`- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
if (textfield.text notEqual @"something"{
  //Do something
}
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make bindings validate values automatically there is mechanism of [Key-Value Validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Validation.html).

1. In the object you bind to (the App Delegate) implement either of the following methods:

   ```
   - (BOOL) validateValue:(inout id *)ioValue forKey:(NSString *)inKey error:(out NSError **)outError;
   - (BOOL) validateText:(inout id *)ioValue error:(out NSError **)outError;
   ```

   The first one is generic and will be called to all keys, the second one will be called specifically for key `text`.
2. Enable “Validates Immediately” checkbox.

If validation method returns `NO`, a standard error sheet will be displayed, with options to revert value back to what it was before editing, and to continue editing without setting value in the model object (the App Delegate).

Comment: can you please add little more details? I have an NSTextfield, in some view hierarchy, and a controller object (FileOwner). What (of the text field) should be bound to what (of the controller class) ?